# Can't get the order correct in sqlite query

Tags: sqlite

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     rev1.name,
     rev2.name

FROM reviewer rev1,
     reviewer rev2,

    (SELECT r1.rid AS r1id,
            r2.rid AS r2id
       FROM rating r1,
            rating r2
      WHERE r1.mID = r2.mID
        AND r1.rid < r2.rID
   ) AS raters

WHERE rev1.rid = raters.r1id
  AND rev2.rid = raters.r2id

ORDER BY rev1.name DESC;
```

This sqlite code returns the following pairs:

```
Brittany Harris   Chris Jackson
Chris Jackson     Ashley White
Daniel Lewis      Elizabeth Thomas
Elizabeth Thomas  James Cameron
Sarah Martinez    Mike Anderson
```

The names in the pairs are correct, but some of them should display the other way around, that is to say, the result should be:

```
Ashley White      Chris Jackson
Brittany Harris   Chris Jackson
Daniel Lewis      Elizabeth Thomas
Elizabeth Thomas  James Cameron
Mike Anderson     Sarah Martinez
```

I would be very grateful if somebody could point out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any help offerred.

Comment: maybe you should add rev1.name < rev2.name in the inner select?

Comment: That sounds logical. I'm not sure where to add that, though, could you please show me?

Comment: Btw biziclop, thanks for cleaning up the code in my question :)

Comment: SQLFiddle to play with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3d026/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the < to <> inside the inner select, then you will get each pair twice, then add constraint for the name in the outer select, something like (look for ### HERE).
Also I think you want ASC not DESC

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     rev1.name,
     rev2.name

FROM reviewer rev1,
     reviewer rev2,

    (SELECT r1.rid AS r1id,
            r2.rid AS r2id
       FROM rating r1,
            rating r2
      WHERE r1.mID = r2.mID
        AND r1.rid <> r2.rID  -- HERE - give you each pair twice
   ) AS raters

WHERE rev1.rid = raters.r1id
  AND rev2.rid = raters.r2id
  AND rev1.name < rev2.name  -- HERE - will remove duplicate pairs
  ORDER BY ASC
```